# dynamic array in recursion with different compiler

Tags: c++

I write it to count the inversion of number and I run it fine in `gcc version 4.2.1 20070831 patched` but when I run it on codeblock  using `mingw32` it close accidently.

I debug and find it was in the `int *left = new int[middle];int *right = new int[length - middle];` but `it just come to error when it recursive on second time`,and I don't know why it cause error and don't know how to fix it.

My questions are

1.How to fix the error?

2.Is there any other heap lost I didn't delete, because I am not sure just want to check it.

Thx in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int invCount(int*, int);
int merge(int*, int*, int, int*, int);
int main(void){
    int array[] = {0, 1, 4, 3, 2};
    cout << invCount(array, 5) << "times" << endl;
    return 0;
}
int invCount(int *array, int length){
    cout << "length:" << length << endl;

    if(length <= 1){
            return 0;
    }

    int middle = (length + 1) / 2;

    cout << length << endl << middle << endl << length - middle << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int *left = new int[middle];
    int *right = new int[length - middle];


    for(int i = 0; i < middle; i ++)left[i] = array[i];//error
    for(int i = middle; i < length; i ++)right[i] = array[i];//error

    return invCount(left, middle) + invCount(right, length - middle
    ) + merge(array, left, middle, right, length - middle);
}

int merge(int* array, int* left, int leftLength, int* right, int rightLength){
   int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;

   while(i < leftLength || j < rightLength){
       if(i == leftLength){
           array[i + j] = right[j];
           j ++;
       }
       else if(j == rightLength){
           array[i + j] = left[i];
           i ++;
       }
       else if (left[i] <= right[j]){
           array[i + j] = left[i];
           i ++;
       }
       else {
           array[i + j] = right[j];
           j ++;
           count += leftLength - i;
       }
   }
   delete[] left;
   delete[] right;
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use pointers for your `left` and `right` variables in your `invCount` function?  You could save yourself misery and use `std::array<int>(5)` instead.

Comment: Whenever I think about C++ and dynamic arrays, I automatically think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: As for the error, have you tried running in a debugger? What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *right = new int[length - middle];
...
for(int i = middle; i < length; i ++)
   right[i] = array[i];//error
```

You're writing way past the end of `right`.

I suggest you use : `std::vector`, with the `at()` function (which does bounds checking).

As for your question about 'heap lost' ( I assume you're asking about memory leaks...) I think your code is ok-ish, but just bad style: `left`and `right` should be deleted in the same function that allocated them, rather than in `merge`. Either way, you will leak memory if an exception is thrown, which is yet another reason to prefer `std::vector`.

Comment: Can I ask you if that I change it to std:vector , the execution will be faster or not? Thx

Comment: @Liang-YuPan : Try it and see. If you can detect any performance difference I'll be surprised. The reliability, readability, maintainability and general craftsmanship of your software will *all* be significantly improved, so you'll waste less time debugging.